# EF Core Seeding mechanism doesn't insert data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I'm trying to create a WCF application with EntityFramework, In-Memory DB and a DB seeder. But I'm stuck. I don't know why this is sooo unbelievable troublesome with C#. In Java this would be a 10 minutes task and this thing would run.. Anyway here's my `DBContext` code:

```
public class AppDBContext : DbContext
    {
        private static readonly DbContextOptions options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDBContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase("INMEMO-DB").Options;

        public AppDBContext() : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>().HasData(
                new Notification
                {
                    Id = 1
                },

                new Notification
                {
                    Id = 2
                },

                new Notification
                {
                    Id = 3
                }
            );

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm using the `OnModelCreating` method to seed data into my db. The method gets called but no data will be inserted. What am I doing wrong?

I'm running out of patience with this C# stuf..

Comment: You need to to call the `Database.EnsureCreated()` method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Comment: Yeah nice it was just that... Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HasData` method only configures the entity to have seed data.

To actually seed the Database you need to call

```
Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Note that this only applies if the databases doesn't already exist (as In-Memory DB's) since `EnsureCreated` does nothing otherwise.

For an existing database you need to create and apply migrations.

For reference: [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding)